# Leave the times out!

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

Everyone knows, that you can leave out the multiplication symbol (\$\times\$, or `*`) in

- `a*b`
- `23*a`
- `(2+3)*a`
- `a^(b*c)`
- `(a+b)*(c+d)`

but not in

- `2*3` => you don't want it to be 23
- `a*23` => most mathematicians just don't do it
- `a^2*b` => now it's `(a^2)*b`, if you remove the `*`, it's `a^(2b)`
- `a/2*b` => now it's `(a/2)*b`, if you remove the `*`, it's `a/(2b)`
- `a*(2+3)` => most mathematicians just don't do it

But does a program know it to?

## Notes

- The input is an equation which has the basic operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^`), parentheses (`(`, `)`) and sometimes some 1-letter variables
- The output should be the input with unnecessary `*`s removed where possible

## Examples

```
a*b
> ab

2+3*a
> 2+3a

23+67/(56+7)
> 23+67/(56+7)

2t
> 2t

2*3+5/6*b
> 2*3+5/6*b

2*a*3
> 2a*3

2*-3
> 2*-3

a*-3
> a*-3

a^2*b
> a^2*b

a/2*b
> a/2*b

a*(2+5)
> a*(2+5)

(2+5)*a
> (2+5)a

23+(2*a)^(45*b)-c/5+24d+(2a)*(2b)
> 23+(2a)^(45b)-c/5+24d+(2a)(2b)

(a-b)*(2+e)
> (a-b)(2+e)

a*b*c
> abc

2*(3)
> 2(3)

(2)*(3)
> (2)(3)

2(3)
> 2(3)

(2)*3
> (2)3
```

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks, it got a bit messed up.

Comment: 5th case `2*3+5/6*b` can't be `2*3+5/6b`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul done

Comment: Maybe it's country-specific, but I've definetly seen and used expressions like `a(2+5)`

Comment: And may we get a single number parenthesized, i.e. `2*(3)`? If so, what should be the output here? (I find it kinda weird, but we *do* use `2(3)` sometimes.) What about `(2)*3` and `(2)*(3)`?

Comment: @Kaddath shall i change it then? i've never seen those before.

Comment: @FZs ok, doing it

Comment: @math Actually I don't think so now you say it, mainly because there are answers already and it's discouraged to do edits that invalidate answers, also because exceptions like this can make challenges more intersting

Comment: @Kaddath I've seen it used on occasion, but it can run into the problem of being interpreted as a function call rather than a product a lot of the time

Answer (score 9):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 5 bytes

```
Defer
```

`Defer` displays the expression in unevaluated form, leaving out the asterisks.

[image]

If you don't mind that Mathematica automatically combines some terms, and just want to eliminate the asterisks, no function is needed, giving the following 0-byte solution:

[image]

When it strips out the asterisks, `Defer` will usually remove mathematically unnecessary parentheses; however, they are sometimes retained for clarity:

[image]

When Defer removes a mathematically necessary asterisk, it will replace it with either parentheses or a `×` glyph:

[image]

For an additional 14 bytes (19 bytes total), Mathematica will dispense with both the asterisks and the times glyphs, using spaces instead.

To accomplish this, we need to operate `OutputForm` on `HoldForm`. Here `HoldForm` is needed instead of `Defer`, because while `Defer` *displays* the unevaluated form, it does not actually return the unevaluated form.  To produce the desired result, `OutputForm` needs to operate on the unevaluated expression:

```
OutputForm@HoldForm
```

[image]

Comment: typical mathematica

Comment: would be good to see an output screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 41 bytes

```perl
s;([/^]\d+\*)|\*(?=[a-z]|(?<=\).)\();$1;g
```

A regex substitution which validates all the test cases.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDNasMwEITvegoTdNAPjlI5csCu6weJk7CyRSmY2m1cKCXPXne1CpT2NPMtI@2wc3gf3WrEVkn2lEUxNb80/KHmoeG2Xq@1OJrzqRt0p@StU6JtjpB/nW6ifWw6uZWdkDXGn1d6d8nCGw/tVG0y6JcPGKs4@pxDv4Sh4mGzgvK4CTxjVhcK0KMCUqHLgxGu1IdY5Q8yu8TRgkYV2pmS/vj1OAZVxFEUpJwgCoMEkOBs03pSBuaOJqESVjtJ6eQYCbUkl3oKXCfPYu@Ul3lvnLb7AYcg8ZW/l48YI/8SFGACch/DOtDVIyXACl71dJ/@e5qXl@n1uua73Tj/AA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 79 bytes

```perl
$_=reverse;s;([a-z]|\((?=.\)))\K\*(?!(\)([^()]|(?2))*\(|\w+)[/^]);;g;$_=reverse
```

Handling tsh's case
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFdbsIwEITffYoU5WHXVjB1MEhYNAfoETBBTrCqSqhJIf1Rxdmbrm0qSp9mvslmd5T0/njQo4QpR/aQBZEm363ze5P7da7MSHD07/548uZkYOOKr@3ZAlTrqUVE@2g5VHdgETY14PYMlULkFs72Q@BG1ls05slcl4xx@y7zr7mvutUkc@3w5g6rEH32vh38fpX7yeh4Q31cw5gSJXfkSR1RKRZLCXohlqHwDTI1hGggw0uh5SLuuHqKHS9DFISoiBCEuQQuQa3S@ajMyQvKhByU0Bink2NRYsvoUk@gc1jDXPMGi1ZqoeZ7Ch3SW82lfMAw8m8iDjBwRROGhY//JlACqtDwNn6flk7VUP6ev/oUg8Y/Dy703fXDc/dyGovZ7ND/AA)

Comment: Then what would `2^(3+5)*a` be?

Comment: @tsh, well it wasn't in the test cases, as this is code golf, it will be a little harder and longer because of recursive structure with parentheses

Comment: @tsh, test case handled

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

Regex solution :

```python
lambda x:re.sub("(?<![\^/].)\*(?=[A-z])","",x).replace(")*(",")(")
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHZbsIwEEXf@Yqpn7wkpE0ISKgp6neEINnGUZEgiRJXokV8e@oFstQvvvfM2GPPND/6q66Svsz2/ZlfxJHDdduqZfctMMK795d8f4iKJdlTvMvyz/C3IChAKLiSZauaM5cKI0KxYcSIxenS1K2GVvVadVryTnWQQb4AszDiVKAAEBeIBA8Us4RyC43gE5yw9SbC6ZptiItO/ZilXUxPCE1YGq19ndFM4pwmLmb3CQ49tftA@YPyOT3Ej284MfLoyaM5pzhmKfEXeTnEnPX/d3LeAWxeSw54lVJBQhmlLF4dDeSm37F4tsV6m/MvxWWMdXgo7Cmm3DFnvZs8U1DppyPNIItFWbegJZwqGEa5dblNe6o0LtFNy/y1uEP2AbcSO0PugC1@KyDLYICmTP8H)

Regex are ugly. Useful but ugly

Thanks to @ovs for -1 byte

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZHZbsIwEEXf@Yqpn7wkpE0ISKgp6neEINnGUZEgiRJXokV8e@oFstQvvvfM2GPPND/6q66Svsz2/ZlfxJHDdduqZfctMMK795d8f4iKJdlTvMvyz/C3IChAKLiSZauaM5cKI0KxYcSIxenS1K2GVvVadVryTnWQQb4AszDiVKAAEBeIBA8Us4RyC43gE5yw9SbC6ZptiItO/ZilXUxPCE1YGq19ndFM4pwmLmb3CQ49tftA@YPyOT3Ej284MfLoyaM5pzhmKfEXeTnEnPX/d3LeAWxeSw54lVJBQhmlLF4dDeSm37F4tsV6m/MvxWWMdXgo7Cmm3DFnvZs8U1DppyPNIItFWbegJZwqGEa5dblNe6o0LtFNy/y1uEP2AbcSO0PugC1@KyDLYICmTP8H) by doing the `)*(` -> `)(` replacement with `str.replace`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 214 bytes

```python
def f(x):
 s=''
 for i,c in enumerate(x):
  if(c=='*'):
   if ((x[i-1:i+2]==")*(")or(x[i-1].isalpha() and x[i+1].isalpha())or( x[i+1].isalpha())and(x[i-2]not in"^/"and x[i+1]not in"-+") ):
    c=''
  s+=c
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZLdboMwDIXveQorN@SnjA1KK1XKXqSiUkiDirRBBanUqeqzs8ShhW5X8fl8nDhxzj/21LX5OB5NDTW9sl0Eg4zjCOquh2aloWnBtJdv0ytrQh6ammopYx6jchIove6b5GPXiKyUkjBOCev6AMu3ZlBf55OiDFR7BAfFEnrjf@icWJ6VbWddE@SQkrl6YokgDEIToLFrGITUEfTGXvoWhjGKrBmsVoMZQMIenZQoXpEVEFURtppQJnKuPHSBWuBcbLYpLTZiyzC71LPLYs4uCM9FkW7CObNY5BXPMefXBU4C9euTqomqV3rIpmtgMPP0wdNXzmkmChY2CuEzhzLcH8PXF6CuW3ag64JXLNFpIbL10UHlxpxVj2fx2nv@WNAxn6OSylcJg2Uog1q0WXEdpqMJi8rIf0SL//A5yjDxc9@0ltbkZvX@vbyD/IRbTVGwO1CPP0qQEp7QHTP@Ag)

ok this is really bad lol, sorry I'm new, any suggestion would be awesome!

EDIT: Ok, I think that's the shortest I can do lol, and FINALLY it works!

thanks to Kateba and Jakque for tips and ideas
EDIT2: not doing lambda because I don't fully understand how it works lol

Comment: I golfed it to [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZJNboMwEIX3OcWUDWMbQgshkSK5F0mJZDugumogAldKFeXs1DaEQL3xvG/eePx3@TWfTZ31Ff/ov8VZngRco46H4T4M11@NrlFB1bSgIwW6hrL@OZetMCVeia5QvfCQhqRpEa8HHb8Va915h1ZIqEVsiezoTdkZJbqyAw6HFdiBgaAyiCAQMiDRiFKWUeGgDcQMZ2y7SzDfsh3x2bl@uozPmRmhGcuT7dBnFPNuVNDMp9w8w/FA3TxRMVKxpMd0PIUPnjx58GTJKaYsJ8NCQzjlvByO78PlBaDdLTniJqeSxCrJWbo5WSiIXUY@bsVp5/ln8Y5nHxFLV8VKX@bloGbblFQNj6MCsipW7jcY/xmml9x776XVtcEquBl1eC3uwN/hVqEX5A7o8FsBnMMEbZv@Dw). But then I realized that test cases 5 to 11 fail with your submission, so please look at the failing testcases and improve your submission

Comment: Some stuff I noticed: You don't need to indent everything with 4 spaces, 1 is enough and saves you a lot of bytes. The list `q` is unnecessary, you could just write `for i in range(len(x))` and `x[i]`. If you need `i` and `q[i]` in your loop, it is best to write `for i,c in enumerate(q)`. In line 5 you write `q[i]`, even if q[i] is the same as `c`. The two if statements can be written together as one, if you connect them with `and`. And finally, you can rewrite the if statement to check for the opposite case and only do `s+=c` then, which saves you a few bytes of indentation and some `not`s.

Comment: @Kateba [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHdboMwDIXv@xQZN@SnlBVKKyGxF2FUclJQM61QQSYxVX12RhxK6XITn8/HcRJff825qeOhyj6Hb7jIE5A@9f3NV6Nrqjjtcx1sUy2iNCo2uqt/LmWrFWVN63P/LVOsalqi14rompSYBVPSnrHBlJ1R0JUdyUi@IuOiHnDprYkH0mPrCUUi5mDhGMACx2J/CGmyFweG2aV@ugzmzILwWCTh3vWZxLIbBx5jyu4LHDhq95nCROGVHqPpFRg8efjg4SvnNBIJcwe5cM6hdM/H8PUD6HhbdqS7hEsWqDAR0e40QmDjMfLxK1Zbzz8LOp59IJC2SpRYhtKpxTUlV244ymOrYmUHa3Cu8yRT9F5bXRtaeTej8vfiTrIPcqsoCnYn1OJtQbKMzHBsM/wB "Python 3 – Try It Online") for 77

Comment: @Jakque I'm still impressed by your skills at golfing. Tried upgrading your code to make it pass the testcases, made it much longer tho for 140 bytes. `f = lambda x:''.join([c*(not((x[i+1].isalpha()or')('==x[i-1:i+2:2])and x[i-2]not in['/','^'])or'*'!=c)for i,c in enumerate(x[:-1])]+[x[-1]])`

Comment: ok I may have something (105 bytes): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHdjoIwEIXvfYpub@yPyAqCCUl9ERaTaYXYjYKBbuLG@OxsWxRwuemc75wybef6a05NHfeV@OrPcJFHQLcM4/V3o2ui8luug02meVQIgSkjOFMfYsmWTUucFRW6xocQ072wkm@Kte7gfD0BoUXVtEivFNI1KuufS9mCKcmN0t6UnVHQlR0SKF8g@xEMTOIVwiAxXT1RxGMGDtoCZjjm6S4kScp31LtzPaWM98yMsJgnYTr0mcTMBxZ7z60zHAzUrSOFJ4V3eoie1/DFxMMXD985IxFP6PCjoRw9L4f7@/L9BYg9LT2QbcIkDVSY8Gh7tBDshCL5ehanXeZfxCemPhBIt4uXfpuXg5odUzI1TEdhuigWbrLGD3YcZeaz11bXhlT4blT@WTyQ2KN7RbygD0Qc3hRICDRC26b/Aw "Python 3 – Try It Online")